# Using NumPy arrays with Keras (2.4.3) and Tensorflow (2.4.1)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I want to implement a lambda layer or custom layer in Keras that passes an input tensor's values to an external library that accepts and returns Numpy arrays. This library performs a physical simulation which I cannot reasonably reproduce using the tensorflow.experimental.numpy or keras.backend modules.

I see that this is a common issue with many questions and answers on StackOverflow and GitHub. However, I've not been able to find a solution that works with the versions of Keras and Tensorflow that I have installed (which are currently the most recent versions on PyPI).

So far, I have ensured that eager execution is enabled, tried using Keras custom layers instead of lambda layers and experimented with different methods of performing the conversion (e.g. tf.make_ndarray and tf.convert_to_tensor). In each case, I trigger an error indicating that the function is not being executed eagerly, for instance:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'tensor_shape'

I have observed that `tf.executing_eagerly()` returns false when called from within a function being used in a lambda layer. I understand that the issue stems from the parent class of the Keras layers not being included in eager execution - but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Below is a minimal reproducible example. The code executes if line 31 is removed.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
print(tf.executing_eagerly())

def function(input_tensor):
    print(tf.executing_eagerly())
    array = tf.keras.backend.eval(input_tensor)
    array = array + 0.2
    out = np.empty([1,sample_dim])
    out[0,:] = array[:]
    return tf.keras.backend.variable(out)

samples = 20
sample_dim = 10

x = np.empty([20,10], dtype = np.float32)
y = np.empty([20,10], dtype = np.float32)

for i in range(samples):
    x[i,:] = np.array([j + i for j in range(10)], dtype = np.float32)/10
    y[i,:] = x[i,:] + 0.1

model = tf.keras.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(sample_dim)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(sample_dim, activation = "relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Lambda(function, output_shape = (sample_dim)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(sample_dim, activation = "relu"))
model.build()
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss="mse", run_eagerly=True)
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=10, epochs=10)
```

Comment: Just a side note: If you do calculations outside TensorFlow, you will get a gradient of `None` (see the [Introduction to gradients and automatic differentiation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#2_did_calculations_outside_of_tensorflow)). If you want to use numpy functions in a model (and make that op differentiable), consider using `tf.py_function`

Comment: @Edric, I don't think it will work. When you create a custom layer, using lambda, the assumption is that you are building the computational graph. Having things like tf.keras.backend.eval(input_tensor) don't really make sense. Keras can't even build your model. You might have to re-think how you are gonna integrate with your external library.

Comment: @Lescurel, ``tf.py_function`` is a much better fit for what I'm trying to do, thanks.

Comment: @CrazyBrazilian, I think you are right. Failing the suggested approach in the first comment, I may be able to achieve what I am trying to do with a custom training loop. Glad to have been pushed in a more fruitful direction.